# Disable eslint for selected NPM packages in Vue.js 2.x

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, eslint

My Vue.js project uses a Javascript client that has been automatically generated user openapi-generator. Unfortunately, the generated code has issues like unused objects that trigger eslint errors. How can I disable eslint for a selected package in this Vue project?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `.eslintignore` file to ignore specific files and directories

[docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code#the-eslintignore-file)

But your question is a bit strange as it mentions "NPM" package and according to same documentation the `node_modules/` folder is implicitly ignored...

Answer (score 0):

/*eslint-disable */

at the end of the html code, use this